# Ionic and usb device

Tags: ionic-framework, usb, libusb-1.0

Is possible develope an app in ionic that have to comunicate with an usb device attached to smartphone?

I have yet developed a native Android app using [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html), but in Ionic what can I use?

Comment: In ionic you can run application in browser using ionic serve and you can also make apk file using ionic build android but for that you have to set sdk, jdk paths in your system.

Comment: @PareshGami sorry Paresh, but I speak about a low communication level to communicate with an usb device attached to android smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the device serial port to communicate with other devices. Take a look at [Serial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/serial/) from Ionic Native.

Alternatively, look the [CordovaArduino](https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino) plugin that is the base for the Serial plugin from Ionic as mentioned before.